# Additional case for a recursive data type

Tags: haskell, recursion, types, algebraic-data-types, custom-data-type

I'm currently learning Haskell and I want to define my own recursive data type for the currency `Dollar` (just bills, not coins).

My attempt looked like this:

```hs
data Dollar = One Dollar
             | Two Dollar
             | Five Dollar
             | Ten Dollar
             | Twenty Dollar
             | Fifty Dollar
             | Hundred Dollar
```

I showed this to a friend of mine and he said it looks fine BUT he also told me to put an `| End` at the end of the definition. He tried to explain why it is necessary but I couldn't follow his train of thought. Maybe someone in here has an explanation that I can follow. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: This doesn't need to be recursive in the first place; all of your single-argument data constructors should be nullary constructors.

Comment: interesting and unusual definition. probably qualifies as *co*recursive data type... the usual definition would be e.g. `data Dollar = One | Two | Twenty`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This doesn't need recursion**

The problem of describing bills doesn't require a recursive type. Let's start with a list then talk about your "dollar".

**Lists**

Your bills are basically special list with more constructors and no termination.  For example, a normal list is like this:

```
data List a = SomeElement a List | End
```

This means we can construct a linked list such as:

```
myList = SomeElement 1 (SomeElement 2 ( End ) )
```

But if we don't have `End` we have no way to stop the list.  It must be `SomeElement` on and on forever.

```
otherList = SomeElement 1 (SomeElement 2 ( ... oh no, I have to keep going! ...))
```

**Back to "dollar"**

So you have this special list of dollars.  Instead of using `SomeElement 1` for one dollar and `SomeElement 5` for a five dollar bill you have `One` and `Five`.  This allows you to construct a "stack" of bills:

```
myMoney = One (Two (Five ( One ...
```

But you can't stop, unless you make the list cycle such as having `...` be `myMoney` and thus get an infinite list of `One Two Five One One Two Five One One ...`.

**Questioning The Design**

You might just want something simple:

```
data Dollar = One | Two | Five
```

And then you can make a list of dollars (type `[Dollar]`) with normal lists such as `[One, Two, Five, One]`.  By claiming the `One` bill also contains another dollar (which is what `Dollar = One Dollar` means) you create not a single bill but a list of them, which doesn't seem useful.

Answer (score 7):

Your friend is probably indicating that at some point, you need a base case. Given the definition

```
data Dollar = One Dollar
            | Two Dollar
            | Five Dollar
            | Ten Dollar
            | Twenty Dollar
            | Fifty Dollar
            | Hundred Dollar
            | End
```

you can represent an arbitrary amount of money as a linked list of `Dollar` values, each one representing a single bill and the "rest" of the money. `End` would terminate the list. For example,

```
fortyTwoDollars :: Dollar
fortyTwoDollars = Twenty (Ten (Five (Five (Two End))))
```

However, I don't see a reason to mix the list into this; a single `Dollar` value can represent a bill alone, and you can use a `[Dollar]` value to indicate a collection.

```
data Dollar = One
            | Two
            | Five
            | Ten
            | Twenty
            | Fifty
            | Hundred
            
fortyTwoDollars :: [Dollar]
fortyTwoDollars = [Twenty, Ten, Five, Five, Two]
```